# Convolution with Sums of powers and the Natural Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, generating-functions

I am looking to see if there are any canonical references that deal with the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m{(m+1-i)i^p}$$

Here, $p\in \mathbb{N}$  I don't know if there has been published work with these.  I have a particular generating function that I"m looking at

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^m(1-2x)^{m-1}...(1-(m-1)x)^2(1-mx)}$$

and i don't know if there are any papers or textbooks dealing with it.  I do know it can be written as a double sum

$$\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^ji^p$$

And i know sums of powers can be expressed in terms of bernoulli numbers, but I can't crack the double sum and was wondering if it could be done using bernoulli numbers or some other type of combinatorical sequence of numbers.

Comment: Why not multiply it out and apply Faulhaber's formula?

Comment: I will try that.